# Setting tag of a ListViewItem when used with Data Template

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a **List View**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding  Apparatus.AcidBaseApparatus}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>

                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Tag="{Binding AppratusName}">
                            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding AppratusName}" Background="Azure">
                            </TextBlock>
                            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" MaxHeight="50" Source="{Binding ImageSource}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <behave:ApparatusDragBehavior></behave:ApparatusDragBehavior>
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </ListView>
```

I want to Bind the tag of each ListViewItem to **ApparatusName** as  I have done with the **StackPanel** in the Data Template. I couldn't find any option fiddling with template on my own. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the Binding in `ItemContainerStyle` (targeting `ListViewItem`):

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding  Apparatus.AcidBaseApparatus}">
    <!-- ... -->
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
       <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
          <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding AppratusName}"/>
       </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <!-- ... -->
</ListView>
```